# Practical Limitations to 1-Wire Communication Speed

Tags: digital-communications, 1-wire

What are some practical limitations to the speed of a 1-Wire interface?

Comment: It is not clear whether you refer specifically to the dallas/maxim 1-wire bus, or to communication over one wire in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are two primary factors that affect the design of a one-wire bus.

The first is the edge speed that you can get with the pullup device, which is usually a resistor, but sometimes enhanced with a transistor.

The second is the accuracy of the timing that each device on the bus can maintain. Most devices are single chips without precision timing elements (i.e., R-C timing circuits only), so the tolerances are rather loose. The bus protocol definition needs to take accomodate all of the possible variations in timing over process, voltage and temperature, and still have enough margin to maintain an acceptably low error rate.

Note that the WS2812 and related products operate on a 1-wire bus at roughly 800 kbps. In this case, the bus is unidirectional, which sidesteps the first issue.

Comment: I think the question is about the literal Dallas/Maxim 1-wire interface.

Comment: @Janka: Yes, that's possible, but it could be more generic than that, which is what I wanted to address.

Answer (score 1):

The bit-times are fixed in hardware. There's a 16kBaud standard mode and a 140kBaud overdrive mode.

What you can do with these bits depends on the slave chip. The DS2405 for example lets you address an individual chip on the bus, then pass bit slots and use them for continous PIO data – standard mode only.

Other chips need to more control bytes on the onewire to read or write their PIOs data. That makes them slower.

But, as soon an individual chip is addressed, all what the other slave chips are looking for is the 480µs bus reset low. As long this isn't reached by any pattern of your data, you may even put higher data rates on the bus line.

Answer (score 1):

The practical limitations depend on;

- risetime (Tr), pullup resistance (R) limitations, wire length and thus inductance (L), bit period Tb and stray EMF/MMF induced in loop
- initial estimate is:

  - Tr < Tb = 1/bit rate
  - Tr=L/R and L=1uH/m typical  while R =?  Tb=?
- additional EMI limitiations are EMF = ?mV/m, MMF= ? mA/m with some mutual coupling that induces a voltage to cause  glitches etc
- the advantage is that the signal can be buffered easily as it is daisy-chained to other nodes for short paths with high speed.